# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in Ruby 1.9 and 2.0 using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, macos, ssl, mechanize

I met the problem but don't know how to fix it ?

1.9.3

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/pry-0.9.12.6/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:258: warning: Insecure world writable dir .rvm/gems in PATH, mode 040777
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `block in connect'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
```

2.0

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.9.12.3/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:259: warning: Insecure world writable dir .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin in PATH, mode 040777
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `block in connect'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:857:in `start'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:700:in `start'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:631:in `connection_for'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:994:in `request'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:259:in `fetch'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:440:in `get'
from course_3.rb:76:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score -1):

I workaroud it by `a = Mechanize.new{|a| a.ssl_version, a.verify_mode = 'SSLv3', OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}`
because I need to access `https` URL with Mechanize

Comment: You did not fix it, you worked around it. Unless you use https just because there is no other thing and you don't care about security you should never switch off certificate checking.